Visual Studio 2022 Professional login failed cause of script error
i want to login to my Microsoft live id in Vidual Studio 2022 Professional.
After clicking the login button the login window is opened. Then i type my mail adress in it and the following script error is shown:
script error
neither the yes button nor the no button helps in this case.
After the messagebox is closed, the white login window stays open.
Translated errormessage: An error has occurred in the script on this page. The object does not support the property or method “addEventListener” Do you want scripts on this page to continue to be executed?
can anybody help me in this case?
I installed the latest vs update.
Thanks for supporting me!

Please share more details, like the error in text form. Are you sure this is in any way related to programming? To me, this sounds like a bug in the application you use, where you haven't written any code on your own that relates to this error message?

Are you behind a corporate proxy?

no I'm not behind a proxy.
@Nico Haase:
It is related to the programming IDE Visual Studio 2022. Is it the wrong topic?
I can't copy the error text, all i have is the screenshot.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Still, is this a programming issue where any of your code causes a problem?

It is not an issue of my code. I try to login to my microsoft account in Visual Studio 2022. It is an issue of Visual Studio 2022. I like to connect to azure devops to clone,pull,commit code.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it - if you are facing any problem with existing software, it's usually better to report this to the maintainers of that software

you can try go to file -> account settings -> account options.
in environment, Acounts, in the right hand, instead of embedded web browser choose system web browser.

But if i will connect to azure devops and pull an branch. the same dialog came with the same script error. I thin it is the git credential manager login page. Can i change the setting for this too?

I don't know neither, please let me know when you find out :D

Visual Studio's Sign-In was down at the time the question was posted. Please try again and see if that fixes the issue.
See below
https://vsstatus.visualstudio.com/
Hope you are no more facing this issue.
